# Executing function certain number of times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to programming so this question may be really basic but I need some help.
I have a code for generating a message a certain no. of times from input given by the user.

(ex.)

```
   var count=document.getElementById("count").value;
   for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
{ 
  GenerateMessage();
}
function  GenerateMessage()
{
 \*
   ...*/
 }
```

But no what matter the value of count is the function is executed only once. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Works fine with breakpoints. But during program execution program generates one message irrespective of count value goven by user

Comment: "Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet" -cit.

Comment: There is not a lot of context to the question here Drake. What exactly does the body of the GenerateMessage function do in your case that makes you believe it is being executed only once. Also, try printing out the value of count before including in the for loop, to ensure that the value being returned in not 1 all the time.

Comment: @BackSlash Just a general programming query. Not limited to javascript only

Comment: @Rohit I'm supposed to write a file depending on count value given by user. After execution only one file is written irrespective of count value

Comment: @BackSlash I am gonna use the same phrase for all the future references :) Nice one..

Comment: Your provided code working fine

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
document.getElementById("count").value
```

Value is a property, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

try this **//jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/286/** its useful for you